# Can Java Enums shares some common codes among them?

Tags: java, enums

I have two Enums as below

```
public enum Read {
    PRIVATE (1), PUBLIC(2);

    private final int value;

    Read(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And

```
public enum Write {
    CREATE (1), UPDATE(2);

    private final int value;

    Write(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Both enum needing some values to represent them. Is there a way for us to share the code, where the `Read` and `Write` "extends" from something that has `value`, instead of for every enum, I need to have `getValue`, `value` etc? Probably one way is to make a class, but thinking if we could make Enum "extensible"?

Comment: You can implement an interface, but you can't extend another class, since all enums implicitly extend `Enum`.

Comment: Ya, but interface still need to write the underlying codes. It just ensure all the enums have the appropriate function :(

Comment: In Java 8 interfaces can include stateless method implementations, but I don't think you're going to find any way to inherit the `value` field.

Comment: As a note, Lombok would be able to autogenerate that boilerplate with `@Getter @AllArgsConstructor`. Also, `value` is a dangerous name--it's exquisitely vague. Better to use something like `bitmask` or `sqlValue` instead.

Comment: Why do you even have setters and getters on an enum? I think of enums as consts. You could just initialize the value in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Don't fight it; embrace classes.

Enumerations generally represent some form of state; that is, each enum value has a specific business-associated state with it.  You'd have to decide what `Read.PRIVATE` and `Read.PUBLIC` truly represented, but they're still states.  The same is true of `Write.CREATE` and `Write.UPDATE`.

The real question now becomes, how do these two enums relate to one another?  They likely don't, given that reading something is independent and severable from writing something.

In this instance, I'd probably represent it in a class:

```
public class Permission {
    private Read readState;
    private Write writeState;

    public void setReadState(Read readState) {
        this.readState = readState;
    }

    public void setWriteState(Write writeState) {
        this.writeState = writeState;
    }
 }
```

It's unclear what the values would represent, since the enums are guaranteed unique, but take from this what you will.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) to hold permissions like this:

### Permission:

```
public enum Permission {

        READ_PRIVATE, READ_PUBLIC, WRITE_CREATE, WRITE_UPDATE;

}
```

### User:

```
public class User {

        private final EnumSet<Permission> permissions;

        public User(Permission... permissions) {
           this.permissions = EnumSet.copyOf(Arrays.asList(permissions));
        }

        public boolean hasPermission(Permission permission) {
            return permissions.contains(permission);
        }

        public void addPermisssion(Permission p) {
            permissions.add(p);
        }

        public void removePermisssion(Permission p) {
            permissions.remove(p);
        }

}
```

### Usage:

```
User user = new User(Permission.READ_PRIVATE, Permission.WRITE_UPDATE);

if ( user.hasPermission(Permission.WRITE_UPDATE) )
{
    //do something...
}
```